# Security model for availability of information

Tags: access-control, availability, cia

I have read about different security models that ensure the confidentiality and integrity of information such as the Chinese wall (confidentiality), Biba (integrity) and Clark-Wilson (integrity). However, I have not come across any security models that focus on the availability of information i.e. the 'A' in the CIA triad. Does such a security model on availability exist?

Comment: I don't think there's a 'security model' for availability in the same sense that we have a security model for confidentiality or integrity.  In my experience availability is mostly about policies and technical controls (load balancers, capacity, rate limiting, etc.).